# No module found cv2 in IDLE

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install opencv3.0 on my ubuntu system. I installed it according to link : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/#comment-429946

At the end, in the terminal,when I try to import cv2, it works. But in the python IDLE it does not work. It gives the error : "No module named cv2".

Also, whenever I try to enter workon cv command, it says : "Error: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate'instead of'deactivate'."
Althoug it gives error, I can get in cv environment((cv) ali@ali-pc:~$ ).
I am new to ubuntu and opencv. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of your IDLE interpreter settings. I use Pycharm and set to project interpreter path to my virtualenv interpreter with installed opencv-python. After this import works.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving version

```
pip install opencv==4.1.0.25(latest version)
```

Check

```
pip list
```

If not listed search location of python

```
which python
```

Search for site-packages folder inside resultant location of 'python' (usually under lib/python3.5/site-packages) and check if opencv-python present or not(packages are not installing right location)

```
sudo apt-get install opencv-python
```